# Dumbbell bench press tutorial

Tags: bodybuilding, chest, hypertrophy

I need a full definitive guide for dumbbell bench press but when i search on web, i get only results for barbell bench press.

---

Any source you know?

Comment: What criteria do you want fulfilled? What do you want to know about? Unless the guide is very boring, long and detailed, it will never account for everything. And I doubt that such a guide would be helpful. You need to filter information. Perhaps share those barbell guides that you want for the db. And remember, when asking on the internet, people cannot read your thoughts. Think about it: the more detail and thought you put into your initial question, the more helpful answers can be

Comment: I want to learN the way how a excercise is learnt like barbell excercises in the "starting strength" book

Answer (score 0):

There are [quite a few results](https://www.google.com/search?q=dumbbell%20bench%20press), what do you consider fully definitive?

My preference is to go with [ExRx](https://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/PectoralSternal/DBBenchPress) as they usually analyze exercises concisely.

Comment: Nothing new.....